# Is it possible to create a custom compiler directive in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, preprocessor

Imagine you don't want to enable `GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS`. Because you are working on an epic legacy code and you don't want to make all 999+ warnings to be errors! But we want it for some cases:

```
#if DEBUG
#warning("Change this on production")
#else
#error("Change this on production")
#endif
```

Is there a way to create a custom one? For example something like:

```
#criticalWarning("Show correct message for errors")
```

Comment: IDK if this is possible. Does your deploying process involve taking manual steps to change something in the codebase for production?

Comment: Although It's just an example, but unfortunately yes. Sometimes in old legacy code there is no time to actually adapt things, besides you need to just mark the code with `TODO`, `FIXME`, `#warning` and etc. @Alexander